# Sudden reference warning in PyCharm

Tags: python, pygame, pycharm

Basically I have been using PyCharm for awhile now, and I have been working with some code. I was showing this code to some team mates of mine, and then when I opened up the code again when I got back to my desk I had some reference warnings:

[image]

I am using Python with PyGame and the full warning is as follows:

[image]

I am getting this warning throughout my code on PyGame on: init, display, time, event, quit...

Literally had none of this one minute, changed nothing, open it up gain and I'm getting these warnings. The code still runs perfectly fine, however the warnings are more annoying than anything. Could someone please help me out with this? It would be most appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: [Invalidate cache and restart](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/cleaning-system-cache.html).

Comment: @Rogalski Warnings disappear until I run the program again.

Comment: Also make sure you didn't name any files `pygame.py` or create any folders that might look like a `pygame` package.

Comment: @user2357112 yep, that's another likely reason.

Comment: @user2357112 No luck, the code is located in a folder `Python_Projects` with the file name being `key_input_test.py`

Answer (score 0):

This is a common error in most of the [jetbrain-ide](/questions/tagged/jetbrain-ide)s and [[image]android-studio](/questions/tagged/android-studio).
`invalidate caches/restart` worked for me.

Go to `files` ->  `invalidate caches/ restart`.